# Connnect to a postgres database on the localhost with pyspark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, connection

I am trying to connect to a postgres database with pyspark. My code looks as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "C:/Users/.../Documents/HWH/projecten/spark/postgresql-42.5.0.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()


df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres") \
    .option("dbtable", "chicago_crime") \
    .option("user", "postgres") \
    .option("password", "postgres") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o128.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at ...
```

It says the class is not found. Does this mean the path to the jar is not correctly specified?

Anything would help!

Comment: Do you have postgresql-42.5.0.jar in the C:/Users/.../Documents/HWH/projecten/spark/ folder?

Comment: yes I have this jar on this location!

Comment: How about adding `.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:/Users/.../Documents/HWH/projecten/spark/")`?